# CASE WHEN [COLUMN] IS NULL THEN '0' ...Not Working

Tags: sql-server-2012, case, isnull

The following is a simple query that I am running to rectify `NULL`s by making them `'0'`:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN R.P IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE R.P END AS 'RectifyNull'
FROM 
    RBase r
```

This is still returning me `NULL` values when I want a string value of `0` in the results instead of the `NULL`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the value is actually `NULL`?  Your `case` statement should work, but there are other alternatives such as `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`...

Comment: stop downvoting everyone's answer, they have all provided valid methods of fixing your problem, your problem is not stated correctly or you haven't given accurate information.

Comment: As a follow-up, try `SELECT * FROM RBase WHERE P IS NULL` -- get any results?  How about `WHERE P = ''` or even worse `WHERE P = 'NULL'`?

Comment: Caught the problem.  The results are actually literal `NULL`s...  Had to search for = 'NULL'...Thanks for the brainstorming all.

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this question for being "off topic"?  This is a basic programming question.

Comment: flags... downvotes... sometimes people are quick to criticize but not as quick on the praise. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

how about `COALESCE`?

```
 SELECT COALESCE(`R.P`, '0') as 'RectifyNull'
FROM 
    RBase r
```

Comment: I tried that already and just retried again and still receiving `NULL` results...I also tried `ISNULL()` and still received `NULL` results.

Comment: is it the string 'NULL' or is it a `NULL`, there is a difference

Comment: Problem was that was actually string `NULL`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What you've posted *should* work, are you sure you're encountering `NULL` and not empty string? ('')

Another way of writing it would be:

```
SELECT isNull(r.p, '0') as 'RectifyNull'
FROM RBase r
```

to deal with empty strings ('') and NULL strings

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN R.P IS NULL THEN '0' 
        WHEN r.p = 'NULL' THEN '0'
        ELSE R.P 
    END AS 'RectifyNull'
FROM 
    RBase r
```

Comment: it is most likely not an empty string; empty strings show up as blanks, not NULL.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to use the "isnull" function.  What isnull will do is it will replace null values with the value you specify in the second parameter.

ex-

```
select 
R.P
, isnull(R.P, '0') as replacingNulls
from RBase r
```

EDIT:  if the NULL value is not actually a NULL, and instead a string literal "NULL", then you should use a case statement like so:

```
select 
R.P
, case when R.P = 'NULL' then '0' else R.P end as replacingNulls
from RBase r
```

Comment: I tried that already and just retried again and still receiving NULL results

Comment: @JeffOrris then are you sure they are actual NULL's, and not just a string value of "NULL" ?  if it is just a string literal "NULL", then use a case statement.